# Find the cumulative distribution function of Y = XII{X ≤ b}.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that X is a continuous and nonnegative random variable with the cumulative distribution function Fx. Let b > 0.

a) Find the cumulative distribution function of Y = XII{X ≤ b}.

b) Apply the general formula from (a) to exponential distribution with parameter 
λ > 0.

I'm having trouble understanding the notation for Y = XII{X ≤ b} What does "II" mean?

Comment: X = 10. And XII = 12.

Comment: So it's like saying Y=X+2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that 
$$
Y=XI(X\leq b)=\begin{cases}
X&\text{if}\, X\leq b\\
0& \text{if}\, X>b
\end{cases}
$$
so $Y$ equals $X$ truncated at $b$.